# How to list all the files changed by a perforce change list

Tags: perforce

I have a specific change list, and from the command line I want to list all files that were a part of that change list.  How do I do this?

Comment: Probably the easiest way: `p4 files @=<cl>`

Comment: @user114245 That's much more precise, you should add an answer

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That's the [describe](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/describe.html) command. To describe a particular changelist, you want `p4 describe <changelist number>`.

**Update:**

If you only want the file names, you can use the [files](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_files.html) command with the -F option to override the output format: `p4 -Ztag -F "%depotFile%" files @=<changelist>`

See http://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting for more information about the -F option.

Comment: This is the command I need!  However, it's pretty verbose.  I can exclude the diff'd code with -s, but is there a way ONLY list the files changed?

Comment: @coffee If you're comfortable with Python, you can run `p4 -G describe -s <changelist number>` and it will cause the output to be formatted as marshalled Python dictionary objects, which you can then parse and retrieve only the files.

Comment: I had to put @=<changelist> in quotes, eg. "@=1234" if 1234 is CL number

Comment: If you'd like to set up a convenient p4 describe tool in your visual client, select Tools | Manage Custom Tools, New | Tool, and in the resulting dialog set the following:
* Name: Describe Changelist
* Add to applicable context menus: True
* Application: p4
* Arguments: describe -s %c
* Run tool in terminal window: True.

This provides a convenient context menu item usable on changelists other than the default and outputs to a terminal window for convenient copying.

Answer (score 38):

[user114245](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404462/user114245) gave the best answer, but only in a comment. I'm adding as an answer to give it more visibility, and to improve a little.

For change 12345, this is the closest you can get with just a `p4` command

```
p4 files @=12345
```

which gives only this output

```
//depot/file1#3 - delete change 3 (text)
//depot/file2#3 - edit change 3 (text)
//depot/file5#1 - add change 3 (text)
```

If you want to remove the extraneous info about each file, you'll need to process that output through more tools on the command line. Assuming a standard unixy environment, you can use a single `sed` command like so

```
p4 files @=12345 | sed s/#.*//
```

to get the desired result

```
//depot/file1
//depot/file2
//depot/file5
```

---

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387381/445073) by Mike is this

```
p4 describe 12345
```

which gives all of this extra detail in the output

```
Change 12345 by day@client1 on 2013/06/21 00:25:28

    Some example changes

Affected files ...

... //depot/file1#3 delete
... //depot/file2#3 edit
... //depot/file5#1 add

Differences ...

==== //depot/file2#3 (text) ====

1c1
< This is file 2
---
> This is file 2 - edited
```

That was improved on by [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9525505/445073) which uses grep and awk to filter out the noise and just leave the files changed, but the command is quite long

```
p4 describe -s 12345 | grep '^\.\.\.' | awk '{print $2}'
```

I think the solution given here is neater.

Comment: `p4 fstat -T "depotFile" @=12345` is pretty good too. But you have to trim off the `... depotFile ` leading text.

Answer (score 7):

Mike O'Connor's answer helped me too.

As for just getting a list of files changed, couldn't it just be as easy as this?

```
p4 describe -s {change number} | grep '^\.\.\.' | awk '{print $2}'
```

that's what I'm going to use.

Comment: You can move the regular expression pattern into your awk script: `awk '/^\.\.\./{print $2}'`

Answer (score 6):

If your changelist is still pending, you can run `p4 opened` or `p4 opened -c <changeListNumber>` for a specific (unsubmitted) changelist number.

From the [official documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_opened.html):
"List files that are open in pending changelists."

Answer (score 2):

p4 change -o

It has the list of files at the end.

Comment: For **submitted** changelists, no it doesn't. The Files section is only shown for pending changelists. The output for a submitted changelist actually has a comment describing the Files section which says `What opened files from the default changelist are to be added to this changelist.  You may delete files from this list. (New changelists only.)`

Comment: With version 2013.1, the "Files" section isn't even shown for pending changelists, from what I can see.